# How to import Custom Post Types of wordpress into Drupal?

Tags: 7, migrations

I've a wordpress site with around 500+ posts of a Custom Post Type with some custom fields attached to them.

I want to migrate them to Drupal. I've tried using `wordpress_migrate`. But it doesn't seem to work! This module didn't even seem to recognize the Custom Post Types. How can I import them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently available in `wordpress_migrate` however there is a feature request open here. https://drupal.org/node/1580412

Your best option would be to write a custom migration using Drupal's [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module. You would need to write a custom source to load your data from WordPress and you'd be able to look at `wordpress_migrate` for help as needed.